# CSS confuse: Why people used to horizontal padding to link text?

Tags: css, padding

Recently I read some tutorial about how to make pure CSS drop-down menu:

- http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu
- http://designmodo.com/css3-dropdown-menu/
- http://red-team-design.com/css3-dropdown-menu/

I found them when dealing with links in the `li` items, they used to add horizontal padding to the `<a>` element.

Code like this:

```
li a {
    padding:0 20px;
}
```

In my opinion, event without the padding, it won't effect the functionality or visual effect. The only reason adding the padding I guess is padding will make click area more bigger?

Could someone explain about this?

Comment: Remove the padding and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the padding on those elements will have a large effect on the visual effect on the list items in question.

Taking your 3rd link as an example, this uses nested lists, a `<ul>` list inside an `<li>` list item of another list.

The `<a>` inside the nested list item has the following padding rule:

`padding: 10px;`

This creates the space around the text, and without it, the list would look cramped and put simply, unnatractive.

On the main navigation bar, there is a padding rule on #menu a,
`padding: 0 25px;`, which I assume is what your original question was about.

Take away this rule, and you'll notice a massive change. All the list items will appear right next to each other with no spacing, instead of nicely spaced out. As you mentioned, you don't need to use padding here, `margin: 0 25px;` would have a similar appearance, but with a smaller clickable area.

Long (and convoluted, sorry) answer, short conclusion. 
Yes, you are right in that the padding is unnecessary and could be replaced by another rule such as margin, but that would result in a much smaller clickable area. For UX reasons, the padding method is preferred here. 
Where you're wrong, I'm afraid, is saying that the padding has no effect on visual style. Play around with it in your favourite browser dev tools, or similar, and you'll notice a massive difference when you disable any of the padding rules.

Hope this helps, and I'll be happy to reply to any further questions :)

Comment: I'm wondering if I could use `width` to replace the horizontal padding? Because I think the padding is used to keep space between neighbour item, so after i set some width to each item, and using `text-align:center`, I could achieve the same effect?

Comment: Yes, you can, if there's only text. The difference in the two methods being that using `width` will result in an equal width for each list item, and using `padding` will result in items sized relative to the width of its content - the word itself. I'd say the padding approach generally looks cleaner but it depends on where your using it. Try both and see what looks best, and functions best from a UX standpoint :)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much!